# PHP Session Persistence Between AJAX Posts (Mobile Browsers Mostly)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, post

So I have searched a lot on this topic and there are a few things I should say off the bat:

- Yes, I am using session_start() at the beginning of BOTH pages
- Yes, both of these pages are in the same domain origin
- The session_id() calls return different ID's between the two pages

This is what the page looks like where I am posting from (index.php):

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$session_name = $name.'-'.$id;
$_SESSION[$session_name]['user'] = 'Bob';
```

I then have a post call:

```
$.post(webroot+"/next.php", {}, function(data){});
```

And in next.php I have the following:

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$session_name = $name.'-'.$id;
print_r($_SESSION[$session_name]['user']);
```

This results in nothing being printed, as the $_SESSION variable has been reset with a new session. Also, the value of $session_name is the same between both pages as I have printed and tested. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you changing the session info with the post call? It looks as if you are, because the $_GET array is being populated again.

Comment: The $_GET['name'] and $_GET['id'] are set by a URL rewrite in my .htaccess. These are being set fine. Are you saying that doing this might restart the session?

Answer (score 0):

It's staring you right in the face, but might not be so obvious.

```
$.post(
```

That's `$_POST` not `$_GET`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Instead of

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

In your `next.php`

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I pass some variables into the URL by an .htaccess rewrite which is where the $_GET comes from. Thank you for pointing that out, but that is all working fine as of now.